# How to handle case sensitive column with utf_unicode_ci

Tags: mysql, collation, case-sensitive, collate

I have a mysql database that use **utf_unicode_ci** (case insensitive)

But in one particular case there is a single column of one table where i need to save a **case sensitive unique string** (for example: iX3hR0)

In this case the correct solution is to change this column only in utf8_bin???
(and leave the rest of the db with CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci)

Or there is a better way? Does this method affect the performace?

***EDIT:***
I know that I can use "WHERE BINARY Name='vaLuE'" but I need to store the case sensitive string as unique in the database

Answer (score 1):

use binary operator.
For example

```
WHERE BINARY Name="vaLuE"
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I already know this method but I need to store the case sensitive string as unique in the database as well..